# How do I add to saved data set with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing to a firebase database with:

```
var dataRef = dbRef.child("compareData");
dataRef.set({pairedResult});
```

But when I add:

```
 var dataRef = dbRef.child("compareData");
 dataRef.update({pairedResult});
```

to contribute to the existing data set, it overwrites the saved data and starts over.

When I use .push() it saves and remains on refresh, but it creates a ton of new child sets with the updated data.

How do I make it so that it writes to the compareData child and pairedResult is simply updated in that child, rather than recreated each time and stacked?

Comment: Please update your question to include what is in `pairedResult` and what JSON (as text, no screenshot please) currently exists at `dataRef`.

Comment: pairedResult is a set of arrays